# How to get sagepay repeat payment api

Tags: php, opayo

I have searching a lot. But did not find any API code for sage repeat payment

Basically want to **some document or source  code of sage pay repeat payment**.
So that i will integrate that with php.

I am too frusted on the Api. Can anyone help  me on this .

Answer (score 1):

It's here (it is a bit of a faff to find):

https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/12251/download-document/SHARED_Protocol_Guidelines_010814.pdf